# Laravel cicle foreach of a litteral object

Tags: laravel, object, foreach

I have this problem in my project in laravel.
I have a table `Optional` where `$optional->column_name` with the name of column of `$bookingOptionals`.

I have this code:

```
@foreach($optionals as $optional)
    @if( $optional->column_name == 'coffee_break' ||
         $optional->column_name == 'permanent_coffee' ||
         $optional->column_name == 'permanent_coffeeplus'||
         $optional->column_name == 'integrazione_permanentcoffee' ||
         $optional->column_name == 'quick_lunch')

        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <fieldset>{{ $optional->nome }}</fieldset>
            <input type="text" name="{{ $optional->column_name }}" value="{{ $bookingOptionals['0']->$optional->column_name }}">
        </div>
    @else

    @endif
@endforeach
```

I have this error:

> Trying to get property 'column_name' of non-object (View: /home/vagrant/code/prenotazioni/resources/views/dashboard/optional_booking_edit.blade.php)

Comment: what's the output dd($optionals);

Comment: show {{dd($optional)}}  ` @foreach($optionals as $optional){{dd($optional)}}
                           `

Comment: $optional it's ok, beacause if i print $optiona->name or column_name it's all right.

Comment: $optional is array or object??

Comment: i guess $optional is array(), if you use ->toArray();

Comment: can you show your controller method??

Comment: Post more code, like controller, model, etc etc

Comment: Please post more code. I expect `$bookingOptionals` to be a eloquent collection and you access it wrong. With more info I could give you a detailed answer.

Comment: Your issue is most likely with the `$bookingOptionals['0']`. Show us the output of that. I assume it's a Collection but just to make sure do `dd($bookingOptionals)`

Answer (score -1):

use

```
@php
print_r($optional)
@endphp
```

inside your loop to see what fields it has and make sure column_name is exists, 
and is `$optional` an object? or is it array? then you should remove raw php and probably use

```
$optional['column_name']
```

instead

Comment: Sorry but the meaning of Laravel is not to skip the Framework functions and use raw php instead...

Comment: The raw php in my answer were just for see if that field exists. You should remove it from code.